# Rescue Flex HTMLLoader Crash

Tags: html, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, air

I use HTMLLoader component, and I have to load thousand of different websites per days by this component.

But some times, HTML component produce several crash/days of my AIR application ...

How can I rescue or avoid theses crashes ?

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: By all means do NOT post any code

Answer (score 0):

You can catch unhandled errors listening to UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR

```
    loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener( UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, uncaughtErrorHandler );
```

Comment: Ok thanks Tamas, I'll test that, and tell you if its good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, although it is not perfect, it is work well.

```
html.htmlText = "";
super.removeElement(html);
html = null;
```

that means html will be gc at some time.

if you want gc immediately, you can call System.gc() manually,
like:

```
html.htmlText = "";
html.addEventListener(Event.LOCATION_CHANGE, html_locationChangeHandler);
super.removeElement(html);
html = null;

private function html_locationChangeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    super.callLater(function():void{System.gc();});
}
```

Comment: Thanks andiris, but can I ask you a question ? What is System.gc ? I never heard about this :-) Thank you anyway, I'll test this !